# java- how to retrieve resultset from database without using JDBC?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that acts as a service and picks up emails from the email queue table, processes them and sends them out. Here is something along how I did it, and it does work fine.

```
MySqlConnect con = new MySqlConnect();
public PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;    
public Connection con1 = con.connect();

//pick up queue and send email
public void email() throws Exception {

    try {

        while(true) {

            String sql = "SELECT id,user,subject,recipient,content FROM emailqueue WHERE status='Pending' ";
            PreparedStatement statement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String subject = rs.getString("subject");    
                String recipient = rs.getString("recipient");   
                String content = rs.getString("content");
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                String username = rs.getString("user");
                String emailStatus = "DONE";
                String errormsg = sendEmail(recipient, subject, content, id,username);

                if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                    emailStatus = "FAILED";
                }

                TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);    
            }

            statement.close();
            rs.close();
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        TerminalLogger.printMsg("Exception: "+e.toString());
    }

    con1.close();
    Thread.sleep(2000);    
}
```

Now, I am clearly using `JDBC` to obtain the result set in the loop and process them as shown. Of course, I also need to specify my database connection in `MySqlConnect.java` properties. While all this works perfectly fine, I was wondering is there another way of achieving the same goal without using JDBC, i.e. specifying the connection properties?

I was thinking of Java Persistence. I am new to this.

### Edit

I have been told to use JPA to achieve this and I have written it in this way:

```
public void email() throws Exception {

    try {

        while(true) {

            String sql = "select p.id,p.user,p.subject,p.recipient,p.content from Emailqueue p where " +
                "status='Pending'";

            List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();
            for (Object[] obj : list) {
                System.out.println(obj[0]);
                System.out.println(obj[1]);
                System.out.println(obj[2]);
                System.out.println(obj[3]);
                System.out.println(obj[4]);
            }         
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        TerminalLogger.printMsg("Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
```

From here, I would pass the parameters I want to the method. Is this way feasible?

### Edit 2

Did it a bit different like below:

```
String id = ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().getid();
String username = ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().getUser();
String subject = ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().getSubject();
String recipient = ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().getRecipient();
String content = ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().getContent();
String errormsg = sendEmail(recipient, subject, content, id,username);    

public String getContent() {
    try {
        String sql="Select content FROM emailqueue WHERE status='Pending'";
        if (em == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not found subject");
        }

        return (String) em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just a bit idea of how the method looks like, the other methods follow the same concept.

Comment: Hope you are familiar with ORM (object relationship mapping), you need to have  your table as emailqueue as an entity and can apply JPA over the same ,
you can follow many good tutorials on JPA , one such example is at https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: So I don't really need to use resultset but just keep picking single record and have it in a while(true) loop?

Comment: If the operation on your queue table is kind of OLTP  data keeps on email queue filling all the time, then you have to come up with a mechanism to read it frequently , Spring Batch is a wonderful option for the same

Comment: Spring Batch + Spring JPA should be a very good choice for your usecase

Comment: It's not really OLTP,I basically want to run it as a service 24/7. This means,everything a new record inserts to email queue,then the jpa will pick up and send the email,it goes on and on....

Comment: Then you have to have a schedule your batch like once every min or every 5 mins , that should solve the purpose as batch will do heavy processing in bulk

Comment: Do you have a better tutorial for the JPA to serve my purpose? The link you gave is a bit confusing for me. Also,I would like it to keep running constantly, not every min or so,is it possible with JPA or only can be done with JDBC?

Comment: For Running Constantly  (Spring Batch)  and For Database Operations (Spring  Data JPA) eliminating native query and JDBC, I will lookup a more simple and easy to follow the tutorial in short while

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193297/discussion-between-yugansh-and-daredevil).

Comment: Sure,also I am using Intellij to work with so knowing how to use persistence mapping to import the schema from intellij is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   List<EmailQueue> emailList = em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();
        for (EmailQueue obj : emailList) {
              String emailStatus = "DONE";
              String errormsg=sendEmail(obj.getRecipient(), obj.getSubject, obj.getContent(),obj.getId(),obj.getUsername());
                    if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                        emailStatus = "FAILED"
                    }
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a way I could keep this running? After i insert a new email record with status pending,it doesn't do anything though

Answer (score 1):

Before using JPA ,you must read about it [WHY JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_03/ejb3_overview_why.html)

As discussed in the comments above, Spring Batch and Spring JPA is a good choice for your use-case, 
you can follow and study about on the internet and follow the official document

[Spring JPA tutorial link](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/)

[Spring Batch tutorial link](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/)

Happy Learning, Hope more users would suggest other good options that you can choose from and apply to your use-case post evaluating their pros and cons

Comment: I already implemented the persistence,how do i access the values i want in result set using spring?

Comment: sorry for being bit late ,  here you go this is the simplest yo need to do find All to fetch result set http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/12/jpa-crud-example/ each time inside your while true loop

Comment: Could you check my edited post and see if this would work?

Comment: The only problem with your link I see is it requires me to specify the database name in persistence.xml. I might give my program to someone else and I don't want them to specify the database name in config file.

Comment: I added a new post of my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141425/java-retrieve-fields-from-object-list  you can check it out

Comment: you need to connect to a database without specifying the properties to be used, how that is feasible, even in IntelliJ you need to provide details about DB, it's like connect to X without knowing X (Impossible) , so there will be a file or place where you need to keep the connection properties , so its upto you where you wanna keep them Code or config file

Comment: Yea with my current way of doing it via JDBC,I have a config file with the jar file where the user needs to alter the connection in the config file,I was thinking it i use JPA,does it also require me to alter the connection if I send to a new user to use on their pc via their own database(different name)?

Comment: yes, the config file will contain the Specific Environment DB properties that you need to connect to, JPA is a cleaner way of doing things, Edited the main answer  and added link why JPA is useful over JDBC

Comment: I'm trying to use entitiymanager to achieve it, i will update my post later to show you how i did it. You can give me feedback on it

Comment: this would give you one single record

Comment: Yea but i am passing each single record from the row to my sendemail method

Comment: I don't really need to use loop iteration since it's in a while(true),meaning it's always running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193365/discussion-between-yugansh-and-daredevil).